# Exchanger Server 2010: Forward all emails of a domain to another

Tags: exchange-2010

I am quite new to Exchange Server. We have Windows Small Business Server 2011 that includes Exchange Server 2010. We are transferring our emails from a cPanel to Exchange.

In cPanel, there is an option to forward all emails from one domain to another. So, if have two domains, a.com and b.com and a.com is the main one, I can set it up so that ANYTHING@b.com is redirected to ANYTHING@a.com. This is convenient because I don't have to set a forwarder for each domain.

So, in this first part, I would like to be able to redirect jo.example@b.com to jo.example@a.com as well as any other like jo.example2@b.com to jo.example2@a.com without explicitly setting them (only the domain forwarder).

Secondly, I have found that I can forward a mailbox to somewhere else, but I would only like to add some aliases to a particular mailbox. This may be OK by using the Email addresses tab and having the domain forwarding working. Let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to forward emails from one domain to another. If you're moving your email to Exchange then simply change your DNS MX record appropriately.

Comment: @joeqwerty Some has been changed and they will all be, but currently on cPanel, they are set as one main domain and others only forward emails to the main one. Like this, I don't have to configure aliases (of the same email account/mailbox) for all the domains.

Answer (score 1):

For Exchange, there's no such option to forward message from one domain to others.
Instead, we can set forwarding setting by admin or end user manually.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351134(v=exchg.141).aspx

Moreover, we can create a .csv file, then configure it by script.
For example:

```
Import-Csv c:\temp\users.csv | Foreach-Object{Get-Mailbox $_.DisplayName | Set-Mailbox -ForwardingAddress $_.MailAddress}
```

Comment: Isn't this redirecting a current mailbox to another address? Even though, your answer probably told me that I would have to add all accepted aliases of a mailbox within the Email Addresses tab.

Comment: Yes, we can forward message to other mailbox (ForwardingAddress) or external address (ForwardingSMTPAddress).

If you add other domain as accept domain, and apply it by email address policy. It's a single mailbox with multiple email address, thus we cannot need to configure forwarding for each other.

Comment: I configured it using "accepted domain + email address policy", but I am facing this problem : https://serverfault.com/questions/892770/exchange-server-2010-keep-to-header-unchanged . I just tested creating a new mailbox that redirects to my main one and the "To" header is preserved, but that is fastidious because I want to support like 4-5 base aliases from my 8 domains. So I would not like to create like 40 mailboxes only for one user.