# Exchange Server 2010: Keep "To" header unchanged

Tags: exchange-2010

I am using Exchange Server 2010 and my mailboxes have multiple email addresses configured for all my domains.

When I send an email let say from Hotmail to my server using SENT-ALIAS@SENT-DOMAIN.TLD the "To" header is modified to REPLY-ALIAS-OF-THE-MAILBOX@REPLY-DOMAIN.TLD. To be concrete I am sending an email to abc@abc.com and it is changed to cba@cba.com.

How can I keep the original "To" header so I can see in my email client the real email address it was sent to so I would be able to configure rules upon that information?

I tried to search on Google over and over and I doesn't seem to be able to get the right keywords to obtain what I want.

One thing more, I have a Gmail account that redirects to my own domain email server. Sending from Hotmail to Gmail makes me receive the email in my own domain email server AND the "To" header is not changed. I would like to have the same behavior with all my own domains.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other device or app between Exchange and internet? And, any non-native transport agent?

As an Exchange administrator, we can enable [**Pipeline tracing**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125018(v=exchg.150).aspx) to monitor the  snapshots of messages. Also, use **message tracking log** and **protocol log** to monitor the deliver process those effect messages.

Comment: There is no device or app between exchange and internet. Well, just to ensure mutual comprehension. An email is sent to one of my domain, received by Exchange and then download by my email client on my computer where I see that is my default domain (email address) that is set, not the one I sent to. I will look forward for pipeline tracing and other stuff you propose. Does pipelining effective on incoming email or only outgoing ones?

Comment: Actived pipeline tracing, but no file is created in the appropriate logs folder.

Comment: There is no non-native transport agent.

Comment: I just tested creating a new mailbox that redirects to my main one and the "To" header is preserved, but that is fastidious because I want to support like 4-5 base aliases from my 8 domains. So I would not like to create like 40 mailboxes only for one user.